# Can't call Rest Api from $http.get

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to access a `REST API` which I'm working on. The client for this application is an `AngularJS` website.

When calling the `REST API` I get the following error

> Http request configuration url must be a string or a $sce trusted
>   object.  Received:
>   {"method":"GET","url":"http://localhost:51615/api/Call/2/{\"Request\":\"INIT\"}"...}}

The code I'm using is this:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({
        Request: 'INIT'
    }),
    req = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:51615/api/Call/2/' + json,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }

console.log('req : ', req)

$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(req.url)
$http.get(req)
    .success(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    })
    .error(function (error) {
        console.error(error)
    });
```

The errors tells me that the `$http` url must be a string, but as far as I can see it is. So what might be the problem?

Comment: why do you have the json stringify, have you tried the url without it? docs have the .get method with .get(url,config) you have one object in the argument. if you want to keep the above try using just the basic http without .get.

Comment: As a side note, JSON contains URL-unsafe characters like "{}[]", that should be at least escaped. The POST method is more usual for JSON. If you just need to pass some params via GET, just using the http://localhost:51615/api/Call/2?Request=INIT&foo=5&whatever syntax looks more like REST to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req` is clearly an object. Try `req.url` instead. You can pass your configuration object (`req`) as the second parameter, as [the documentation explains](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

```
$http.get(req.url /*String*/, req /*object*/).then()
```

Note that it is not needed to tell angular the request-method, it's already get in `$http.get`. So your code would work like this

```
var json = JSON.stringify({
    Request: 'INIT'
}),
config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
},
url = 'http://localhost:51615/api/Call/2/' + json;

$http.get(url, config)
    .then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

I'm also unsure if the application/json header in a get request that sends a string is what you want, but that's another story.

---

Another way would be not to use the shorthand for the request, in that case, you can pass the object you created (req) to `$http()`:

```
$http(req)
    .then(s, e);
```